# Difference between += and =+ operators in C++?

Tags: c++, operators

What is the difference between += and =+ operators in C++? I have seen a solution which finds the depth of the binary tree by using =+ operator.

```
class Solution { 
public:
int maxDepth(TreeNode* root) {
    int l,r;
    if(root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        l =+ maxDepth(root->left);
        r =+ maxDepth(root->right);
    }
    if (l>r)
    return (l+1);
    else
    return (r+1);
}
};
```

Comment: There is not `=+` operator.  I would love to see the example.

Comment: To start with, there is no `=+` operator. Can you please tell us where you saw that? Maybe it's the assignment operator followed by unary `+`?

Comment: If you have `x=+1;` that indicates that a value of positive `1` is assigned to `x`

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the response. I think the solution must be definitely wrong. 

Here is the program:

class Solution {
public:
    int maxDepth(TreeNode* root) {
        int l,r;
        if(root == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            l =+ maxDepth(root->left);
            r =+ maxDepth(root->right);
        }
        if (l>r)
        return (l+1);
        else
        return (r+1);
    }
};

Comment: Please ignore my not so clean comment, I am new to the community.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator

Comment: Looks like a misstype

Comment: Very early in its history, C had an =+ that was like today's +=. It was gone long before C++ entered the picture though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

+= means it will increment the `lValue` by Right side value.

=+ means it will assign the right side value (with sign) to "lValue"

```
int a = 5;
a += 1;
cout << a; // Here it will print 6.

a =+ 1;
cout << a; // Here it will print 1 (+1).

a =- 1;
cout << a; // Here it will print -1.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of the difference.:)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s1( "Hello " );
    std::string s2( "Hello " );

    s1 += "World!";
    s2 =+ "World!";

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
World!
```

Operator `+=` is the compound assignment operator that indeed exists in C++ (and many other languages). As you can see in C++ it can be even overloaded for example for standard class `std::string`.

Symbols `=+` are two operators: the assignment operator = and unary plus operator +. In the demonstrative program the unary plus operator applied to ths string literal has no effect.

Here is a demonstrative program of other weird operators.:)

```
#include <iostream> 

int main()  
{ 
    int x = 1; 
    int y = 1; 
    int z = 1; 

    if ( x --- y +++ z --> 0 ) std::cout << z << std::endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly no =+ operator in CPP a code like this
X =+ 2 simply means x equals positive 2. You can probably expand your question by posting the 'solution' you saw